# How can I implement an SQL query that return a record that is the nearest related to a provided date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, rdbms

I am not so into database and I have the following problem working on a **Microsoft SQL Server** DB.

I have a table named **RendimentiGS** that contains informations like this:

```
 ID    FondoID     DataRiferimento       Rendimento     
1651    ISPAI    2015-05-01 00:00:00      2.99000   
1652    ISPAI    2015-06-01 00:00:00      3.04000   
1653    ISPAI    2015-07-01 00:00:00      3.00000       
1654    ISPAI    2015-08-01 00:00:00      2.85000   

1655    ISPAI    2015-09-01 00:00:00      0.00000       
1656    ISPAI    2015-10-01 00:00:00      0.00000       
1657    ISPAI    2015-11-01 00:00:00      0.00000   
1658    ISPAI    2015-12-01 00:00:00      0.00000
```

So, as you can see in the previous table example, the field **Rendimento** contains some data that have a value different from 0 followed by other data having value 0.

It is important to note that from a specific record the following have **0.00000** as value of the **Rendimento** field.

In particuar, in the previous case, after this record:

```
1654    ISPAI    2015-08-01 00:00:00      2.85000
```

all the following record will have **0.00000** as value of the **Rendimento** field.

Now I have to implement a query that given a date (related to the **DataRiferimento** field) of a record having **0.00000** as value of the **Rendimento** field return the last record that have a **Rendimento** field having a value different from **0.00000**.

For example:

Given the date **2015-12-01 00:00:00** that is related to a record having **0.00000** as value of the **Rendimento** field. It return this record:

```
1654    ISPAI    2015-08-01 00:00:00      2.85000
```

that is the "nearest" (related to the **DataRiferimento** field)  record having **Rendimento** field different from **0.00000**.

What is the smartest way to implement a query like this?

Comment: Are all the records in DataRiferomento having a increasing date value? I.e. every new date will be greater value than the last record? Also do the new dates ever have a value outside of 0.0000 in Rendimento?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * from RendimentiGS 
where FondoID = 'ISPAI' and Rendimento != 0 and DataRiferimento < '2016-02-01'
ORDER BY DataRiferimento DESC
```